# Is $\mathrm{Der}(A)$ a free module over $A$ if $A$ is separable space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider a separable Banach algebra $A$, separable means that $A$ contains a countable dense set $B$. Consider the set of derivation defined on $A$, denoted it as $\mathrm{Der}(A)$. Clearly $\mathrm{Der}(A)$ is a bimodule over center of $A$, the question is: is it a free module?

My thought is as follow: Since $A$ is separable, each derivation is uniquely determined by the it's value on $B$, so just like matrices in finite dimension case , it should be a free module.

Comment: Is $A$ abelian? How you define scalar multiplication on the derivations on $A$ otherwise?

Comment: Let $a,b\in A$, $d\in$Der($A$), then $a\cdot d(b)=a\cdot (db)$

Comment: I noticed my mistakes, I have edited the question now.